# java common lib for gwt client and gwt server

Tags: java, gwt

I am wondering is there a way to use a common java lib (external jar) among gwt client and gwt server if

- lib contains serializable objects only?
- the lib doesn't contain *.gwt.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The external lib must contain a *.gwt.xml file in order to specify which packages must be compiled by the GWT compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble getting this to work.  Adding the non-gwt-project to the classpath in Eclipse and referencing those objects in client-side code didn't raise errors in Eclipse but GWT didnt like it when compiling.  I was able to reference an object from outside the GET project in the server-side code and it compiled, but failed at runtime.  I am hoping to do the same thing, if you do come across a solution please let me know.  Thanks!